# Type 'MyApp' does not conform to protocol 'App'

Tags: swift, realitykit, visionos

Newbie here learning Swift and tweaking a VisionOS app.

I am following [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/positioning-and-sizing-windows#Specify-initial-window-size) to specify an initial window size. I have the following code in my *ContentView.swift* file:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .defaultSize(CGSize(width: 600, height: 400))
    }
}
```

When I build the project, I get the following 2 errors:

1. **Type 'MyApp' does not conform to protocol 'App' (line 2)**
2. **'Scene' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context (line 3)**

Any tips on how I can resolve these?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to `import SwiftUI` at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var body: some Scene {
```

To

```
var body: some SwiftUI.Scene {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing SwiftUI in your file:

```
import SwiftUI
```